# Problema con conexión de placa ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

El problema de que estoy teniendo con la placa es que la PC no detecta el puerto al que se conecta la ESP32, esto me pasa con todas las PCs en las que probé. Leí acerca de que hay que instalarle a la placa un firmware desde Linux, lo hice pero todavía sigue sin funcionar

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Lo primero sería revisar el syslog para ver que mensajes aparecen al conectarse via USB. Puedes editar la pregunta para incluir esa información. Sería de utilidad. También el resultado de `lsusb`. Con Linux no necesitas instalar nada para trabajar con Arduinos, ESP8266, ESP32 o lo que sea.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece ser consistente con la temática del sitio (Programación)

Comment: @CandidMoe no tengo los logs en este momento porque lo probé en una pc linux que no tengo pero si llego a conseguirlo lo subo

Comment: @PatricioMoracho las etiquetas me avalan la pregunta

Comment: *esto me pasa con todas las PCs en las que probé* ...

Comment: Hola @Nahuel, las etiquetas son libres, podría haber una sobre jardinería y si nadie la elimina seguirá estando en el sitio, entiende que este sitio es sobre temas de programación, y me parece que tu pregunta esta más orientada a la problemática del hardware.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho son etiquetas oficiales de StackOverflow, jardinería no se encontraría en la info del sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/esp32/info o cambialo por arduino, también vas a encontrarlo

Comment: @CandidMoe me fijo si lo consigo para windows

Comment: Las etiquetas las cargan los mismos usuarios son libres, lo que te comenté es un ejemplo, no por que exista una etiqueta sobre `arduino` es válido preguntar que precio tiene esta placa. en Argentina De todas formas puedes consultar la documentación oficial del sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic para saber sobre que temas preguntar.

Comment: Más allá de las etiquetas, es una mala pregunta porque no hay nada que otros usuarios puedan usar para revisar/probar/entender el problema. Es un ejercicio de adivinación. La respuesta que tiene la pregunta es un gran ejercicio de adivinación que realmente trata de cubrir lo básico pero no sabemos nada de tu situación específica. Revisa la ayuda del sitio para que puedas hacer una buena pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Que versión tienes, esp32c3,s2,s3, esp
Debes ir a administrador de dispositivos  y ver si aparece en ports(COM & LPT) el puerto serie, los kit de desarrollo tienen integrado u puente usb uart, actualmente estoy usando el kit esp32 c3, el adaptador es de silicon labs CP220x USB TO UART Bridge
Fijate si tu pc existe el puerto, este debe estar configurado

```
Bit per scond 9600
Data bits 8
Parity none
Stop bits 1
Flow control none
```

Si no te aparece el puerto es posible que te falte el driver
Revisa en este sitio si no te aparece
https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads